# Using C# to create a frontend for a simple database

Tags: c#, winforms

I've only used C# to create console apps up to now. What I would like to do next is create a c# application that could open a one table database (probably sqlite) and present the data in  table form to the user. I'd like the user to be able to do things like sort by column, search etc. I have a couple of questions with regards to the GUI piece.

What would be the appropriate .Net technology to use for the GUI front end? WinForms?

I would really appreciate a link to a tutorial or worked example of doing something similar

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial) shows you how to create a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx), load database values in it. The [sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171607.aspx) is an automatic property of the DataGridView. The DataGridView is a control used in a WinForms application, which seems the best solution for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation I would start with WinForms as GUI technology - simpler and more mature than WPF.

Here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx

you find an example application for a single table SqlLite DB.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a RAD none generic solution use GRIDVIEW with  winforms ,if you are looking for a generic and flexible solution i liked [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/676455/Generic-Database-Frontend-Filtering-Free-Text-Sear)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for WinForms for the first application. To display your data I'd use a DataGrid which I would feed a DataTable filled with the query result. 
The Grid and the Table have standard sort functionality built in.